# How to combine daily data with monthly data in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have daily data, and also monthly numbers. I would like to normalize the daily data by the monthly number - so for example the first 31 days of 2017 are all divided by the number corresponding to January 2017 from another data set.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

N=100
start=dt.datetime(2017,1,1)
df_daily=pd.DataFrame({"a":range(N)}, index=pd.date_range(start, start+dt.timedelta(N-1)))

df_monthly=pd.Series([1, 2, 3], index=pd.PeriodIndex(["2017-1", "2017-2", "2017-3"], freq="M"))

df_daily["a"] / df_monthly # ???
```

I was hoping the time series data would align in a one-to-many fashion and do the required operation, but instead I get a lot of NaN.

How would you do this one-to-many data alignment correctly in Pandas?

I might also want to concat the data, in which case I expect the monthly data to duplicate values within one month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the information with `to_period('M')` and then use `map`.

```
df_daily["month"] = df_daily.index.to_period('M')
df_daily['a'] / df_daily["month"].map(df_monthly)
```

Without creating the `month` column, you can use

```
df_daily['a'] / df_daily.index.to_period('M').to_series().map(df_monthly)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a temporary key from the index's month, then merge both the dataframe on the key i.e

```
df_monthly = df_monthly.to_frame().assign(key=df_monthly.index.month)
df_daily = df_daily.assign(key=df_daily.index.month)

df_new = df_daily.merge(df_monthly,how='left').set_index(df_daily.index).drop('key',1)

            a    0
2017-01-01  0  1.0
2017-01-02  1  1.0
2017-01-03  2  1.0
2017-01-04  3  1.0
2017-01-05  4  1.0
```

For division you can then simply do :

```
df_new['b'] = df_new['a'] / df_new[0]
```